# How to denote subsets of $\mathbf Z$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integers

Consider an integer $n$ where $a\leqslant n\leqslant b,\ a,b\in \mathbf R,\ b\gt a$. Then, we can denote it as

$$ n \in \mathbf X, \text{ where } \mathbf X := \{\, k\ |\ k\in \mathbf Z \land a\leqslant n\leqslant b\, \}. $$
But what if one doesn't want to define an extra set?

We know that $[\,a,b\,]$ is defined as

$$ [\,a,b\,] = \{\, x\ |\ x\in \mathbf R \land a\leqslant x\leqslant b\, \},\ a,b\in\mathbf R,\ b\gt a. $$

Then, can we denote $n$ (defined above) as

$$ n\in \mathbf Z \cap [\, a,b\, ],\ a,b\in \mathbf R,\ b\gt a \ ? $$
Is this notation okay? I haven't seen it anywhere.

---

**Edit:** fixed the last two lines as fleablood and Vsotvep pointed out

Comment: Yes, your last line is fine, I'd go with that

Comment: I'm not sure I see why you need "$\forall a,b \in \mathbb R, b>a$".  In fact, I think maybe it is incorrect as the specific set isn't for *any* $a,b; b> a$-- it is specific for one particular $a,b$ you have in mind. (Or maybe I'm misconstruing what you mean). I'd personally just use $[a,b]\cap \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @fleablood By writing "$\forall\ a,b\in \mathbf R,\ b\gt a$"$ ^{\dagger}$, I mean "for all real numbers a and b where b is greater than a". Is $^{\dagger}$ incomplete/incorrect?

Comment: But *what* is true for all $a,b$ and $a < b$?  Aren't you trying to define a *specific* set?  Suppose $a=5$ and $b =7$ and the set $[a,b]=[5,7]$.  You don't want to define it as $\{x| a\le x \le y\} \forall a,b\in \mathbb R; a< b$ because it *ISN'T* defined for all $a,b; a< b$.  It's only defined for *THAT* $a,b$.  Or do I not understand you?

Comment: I mean isn't "$\{x|a\le  x\le y\}$ for all $a,b$ so that $a<b$" actually $\mathbb R$.  Take any $k \in \mathbb R$.  Then let $a = k-1$ and $b = k+1$ and $a \le k \le b$ so $k\in \{x|a\le  x\le y\}$ for all $a,b$ so that $a<b$.

Comment: If $n\in \Bbb Z\cap[a,b]$ for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $b>a$, then we have $n\in[0,1]$ as well as $n\in [2,3]$. Clearly no such $n$ exists, so you should not use a universal quantifier. You only consider *some* $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @fleablood So you want to say that $\forall$ should not be used there, right? I actually mean that it is true for real a and b in which b is greater than a. Should I remove "$\forall$" then?

Comment: @Vsotvep and `@fleablood` Now I understand your argument. I will remove $\forall$ as it makes no sense there.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it might not mean something else that is correct so I don't want to say "I'm right; you're wrong" when I could be very wrong, but I don't think you are using it properly in *this* context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation is completely standard. Note that $\mathbb Z \cap [a,b]$ is the set of all real numbers (that are *integers*) living between $a$ and $b$ (including it, if any of these are integers).